# Sublime xdebug breaks at ..."get_option(" without breakpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, xdebug

I have searched and searched but cant find the solution or someone haveing the same issue.

I have a xampp with wordrpress installation. I use sublime with xdebug and it works good to debug my code, but it breaks at many places where i dont have breakpoints.

In different files and places i get options with the wordpress command get_option();.

```
$sub01 = get_option(woomps_sub01);
$sub02 = get_option(woomps_sub02);
```

And in another file it breaks at session->set:

```
WC()->session->set( 'sub_qty' , $total_qty );
```

If i run this it breaks at another line  again:

```
$result = @call_user_func_array(array($class, 'create'), $parameters);
```

Then its runs further and stops at another get_option in another file:

```
$items_left_start = get_option(woomps_limit01);
```

My breakpoint window is empty. I have cleared the cache folder. Is there any other xdebug clear operations i can try to reset this? Or where can i find the information on how to learn how xdebug can interpret this lines as breakpoints?

I found an article about invisible breakpoints, but it was not like this for me. I dont see anything in my breakpoint window.
https://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic43927.html

Im useing the Run function.

Comment: Does this happen to you only with Sublime? I suggest you try other editors (e.g. Netbeans, PhpStorm...) to determine where the problem is, if it's in the PHP configuration or in the IDE settings.

Comment: Okay. I added phpstorm and connected xdebug. It did not break at "the invisible" breakpoints. I then reinstalled xampp to be sure. When i start debugging again in sublime it breaks at this "inivisble breakpoints". The fail must lie in sublime somewhere, but where? hemm....

Comment: I looked through the deafault settings in sublime for xDebug and i see the following: `// Break on exceptions, suspend execution
    // when the exception name matches an entry in this list value.
    "break_on_exception": [
        // E_ERROR, E_CORE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR
        "Fatal error",
        // E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR (since PHP 5.2.0)
....
    ],`  Could something in my code trigger this?

Comment: I think i saw something i should have seen before `[Notice] Use of undefined constant woomps_sub01 - assumed 'woomps_sub01`. I guess this it why it breaks. I will try to see if i can override this settng.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go into `Tools -> xDebug -> Settings - Default` you will see the following setting:

```
    // Break on exceptions, suspend execution
// when the exception name matches an entry in this list value.
"break_on_exception": [
    // E_ERROR, E_CORE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR
    "Fatal error",
    // E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR (since PHP 5.2.0)
    "Catchable fatal error",
    // E_WARNING, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_WARNING, E_USER_WARNING
    "Warning",
    // E_PARSE
    "Parse error",
    // E_NOTICE, E_USER_NOTICE
    "Notice",
    // E_STRICT
    "Strict standards",
    // E_DEPRECATED, E_USER_DEPRECATED (since PHP 5.3.0)
    "Deprecated",
    // 0
    "Xdebug",
    // default
    "Unknown error"
],
```

The "Notice" will break the code i have pasted above. Too tell Sublime/xDebug not to break this code, go into `Tools -> xDebug -> Setings - User` paste the whole code from settings - Default and remove the part about notice. (This maybe not best practise, but works for me).

Comment: Here is the reason why xDebug broke and a solution too it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586899/wordpress-get-option-to-variable-without-use-of-undefined-constant