# Wordpress get_option to variable without use of undefined constant

Tags: php, wordpress

My plugin i have many options. I use get_option and store it as an array so its easier to use.

```
function woomps_get_options() {
    $options = array(
        'sub01' => get_option(woomps_sub01),
        'sub02' => get_option(woomps_sub02),
        );
    return $options;
}
```

This produces this notice for each line:

```
[TIME] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant woomps_sub01 - assumed 'woomps_sub01' in "DOMAIN"\settings\options.php on line 9
```

I dont understand why i should define woomps_sub01 first or how i should define it. But my question is rather: Why is this not a correct way to get a WP option and what is the better way?

Comment: `woomps_sub01` i string or constant ?? if It is string use quote .

Comment: better to know what type of arguments `get_option()` takes .

Comment: Its a string, actually its an INT. But i dident know this, tought learned something from your comment here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php Thank you

Comment: You really should have good knowledge of php in this field.and you should have marked my comment as helpful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is simply telling that you're passing to the function a undefined constant but probably you meant `'woomps_sub01'` as a string.

Just put quotes like this `get_option('woomps_sub01')` and the notice will go away.